# two divs with dynamic width when spanning two lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a mobile site page, I got two divs in a parent roughly set up like so:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="left" style="float:left;"> </div>
    <div id="right" style="float:right;"> </div>
</div>
```

They both have a min-width and margin set.

They display next to each other fine. But I want to set it up so that if the width is too small (say on an iphone), they span two lines and take up the whole width of the page by itself.

At the moment, I can't get the width to dynamic jump to 100% of the page when they span two lines. All it does is the left div sticks to the left and the right div to the right.

I've read somewhere about using inline block, and toying with the overflow and position but I can't get it to work.

Any tips or suggestions?

Thanks.

**edit:**
Here's the css I'm using at the moment

```
<div style="width:96%;">
    <div style="float:left; min-width:220px; margin:10px auto 5px auto;">
        content
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; min-width:230px; margin:0px auto 5px auto;">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use media queries to achieve the result. But media queries are  not fully supported in IE browsers. IE8 has poorest support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

CSS

```
#parent { 
  border : 2px solid #000; 
  overflow:hidden;
}

.parent div {
   min-height: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
}
#left {
  background-color: gray;
  float:left; 
  margin-right:20px;
  width:140px;

}
#right { 
  background-color: white;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:10px;
  min-height:170px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   #left { 
    float: none;
    margin-right:0;
    width:auto;
    border:0;

  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
  </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cUCvY/258/)

Comment: That did it. Thanks. And I'll keep in mind the browser support Bonu mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set media queries for the style tags. Take the CSS out of the inline and set them in the stylesheet instead.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  #left {float:left;}
  #right {float:right;}
}
```

The DIVs then only float to the left and right if the screen is wider than 480px:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left" > </div>
  <div id="right"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already accepted the other dude's answer but yours came with a nice explanation so here's a deserving upvote!